# Version Upgrading Issue: I'm facing problem in upgrading App version in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Elastic Beanstalk App version upgrading issue:
When i try to upgrade Previously Deployed Application i faced tis issue

2020-10-11 13:10:32 UTC+0500
ERROR
During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.
2020-10-11 13:10:32 UTC+0500
ERROR
Failed to deploy application.
2020-10-11 13:10:32 UTC+0500
ERROR
Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0a5874ef628e9db15'. Aborting the operation.
2020-10-11 13:10:32 UTC+0500
INFO
Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2020-10-11 13:10:31 UTC+0500
ERROR
[Instance: i-0a5874ef628e9db15] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error..
2020-10-11 13:10:30 UTC+0500
ERROR
Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.

Any Please help me!

Comment: Have you redeployed the previous version?

Comment: No actually i'm creating database using Migration script in this version

Comment: So have to check the EB logs and identify this "Unsuccessful command " and why it failed.

Comment: 10/11 08:10:30.849913 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [PostBuildEbExtension]. Stop running the command. Error: Container commands build failed. Please refer to /var/log/cfn-init.log for more details.

Comment: 8.922301 [INFO] Executing instruction: Install composer dependencies
2020/10/11 08:10:28.922311 [INFO] composer.json file not found, skip installing composer dependencies.

Comment: composer.json is also there in zip file but i don't why this

Comment: I'm also having this issue. Let's update your question above to include your info here in the comments.